# Slider with container for captions

Tags: jssor

I'm having trouble with the responsive version of JSSOR slider.

I'm using full width slider.

My content and my navbar is in a container of `1250px width margin: 0 auto;`.

What I want is that I put the captions also in this container.

Then the captions will align completely with my navbar and content.

But the slider also scales my container.

Is there a fix that the slider ignores my container?

Here is some demo code:

```
<div class="home-slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <div>
      <img src="img.jpg" />
       <div class="container">
        <div u="caption" t="text" style="position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 70px;">
         <p class="slider-caption-small">Lees meer over:</p>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the `slides` container should be always be scaled along with the slider.

If you want an element not scale with slider, please move it out and specify `noscale="true"` attribute.

```
<div class="home-slider">
  <div class="slides">
    ...
  </div>

   <div noscale="true" class="container">
    <div u="caption" t="text" style="position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 70px;">
     <p class="slider-caption-small">Lees meer over:</p>
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The problem is I can't set any captions for each slide if i do this. You know any workaround for this?

Comment: I got your concern, but unfortunately everything in slide should be always scaled along with the whole slider.

Comment: This means that there is no fix for this :(?. I'm sure more people have this issue.